# Cell Input with Selection Capability in Google Spreadsheet Prompt

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How does one allow the user to select a cell from a Google Spreadsheet Prompt? According to the documentation, there is a way to get text input from the Prompt, but there does not appear to be a way for the user to click a cell and have it auto-fill the textbox.

Is there a workaround that adds this functionality?

References:

- [Google Apps Scripts Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)
- [Google Apps Scripts Prompt Response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the built in prompt dialogue doesn't take a "value" parameter to pre-populate the textbox, you can replicate the prompt with a custom html dialog containing the pre-populated form field.

Use `showModalDialog(userInterface, title)` or `showModelessDialog(userInterface, title)` documented on the at the Prompt response link in your question.

See an example of a custom dialog here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs